# Altering ListView items at runtime

Tags: android

I have a ListView which is defined in a layout XML.   I have another XML whcih defines TextViews that are elements in each of the items in the ListView and in code use the 'inflator' mechanism .   There are 3 TextViews named top, middle and bottom.  During the runtime life of the ListView I change some text in the bottom row of one the ListView items and it results in two lines of text in place of the one which it was.   The bottom row in the TextViews XML has 'single line' defined as "false".

When the app is running and code amends the bottom row in one of the ListView items two lines of text appears but because the depth of the ListView item doesnt change the second line of text is half hidden.

I've pored over the XML and code to try to puzzle out how to amend the depth of the ListView item but without success.   Can it be done and any help as to how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ListView definitely supports this scenario. Make sure your TextView have a height set to wrap_content and also have a minimum height (so they don't appear tiny when there's only one line of text.) When you change the content of a row, make sure to call notifyDatasetChanged() on ListView to tell it to relayout properly.

Comment: Thanks Romain - the wrap_content advice fixed it.